# java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.sqlite.Conn cannot be cast to class com.mysql.jdbc.Connection (Connection are unnamed module)

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, swing

I got this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.sqlite.Conn cannot be cast to class com.mysql.jdbc.Connection (Connection are unnamed module)

I am getting this error when I run:

```
import com.database.DbConnect;
import java.sql.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class mainframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    public mainframe() {
        initComponents();
        conn = DbConnect.connect();
    }
    private void addbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String name = namebox.getText();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO student(name)VALUES('" + name + "')";

        try {
            pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use db-specific classes. Try the following:

```
import com.database.DbConnect;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class mainframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public mainframe() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void addbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String name = namebox.getText();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO student(name) VALUES (?)";

        try (Connection conn = DbConnect.connect(); PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            pst.setString(1, name);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```